# xslt support in go

Tags: c, go, xslt-2.0, xslt

Dear fellow go enthusiasts,

I would need xslt support in a go program.
As far as I know there will be no xslt library in the the near future
and currently there is no binding to a xslt library in go.

What is the FASTEST library on linux or cross platform to do
1) xslt 1.0 transformation
2) xslt 2.0 transformation

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the wanted details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following could be used in a GO program:

**XSLT 1.0 on Linux**:

1. **[Saxon 6.5.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/saxon6/6.5.5/saxon6-5-5.zip/download)** (Java based and should work on Linux)
2. **[LibXSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxslt)** (C-based)

I don't know which one is faster -- one shouldn't make a bold conclusion based just on the fact that one is Java based and the other is C-based.

**XSLT 2.0 on Linux**:

1. **[Saxon 9.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/)** (again, Java based must work on Linux).
2. ????

Even if there is another XSLT processor working on Linux, in my experience Saxon 9.x is factors of magnitude faster than any other existing XSLT 2.0 processor. It is also one of the most compliant.

Comment: I haven't yet tried this, so I can't speak for how good it is.  I offer it up to anyone else who is looking for a solution.  https://github.com/wamuir/go-xslt